# Cannot implement test of a mocked Instance which should be initialized

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I am new to the framework Mockito and i think i get the point of it, but somehow implementing it does not seem to work.

```
public class Rental {

private int daysRented;
private Movie movie;

public Movie getMovie() {
    return movie;
}

public void setMovie(Movie movie) {
    if (movie.equals(null)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Can not set a Movie to Rental");
    }
    this.movie = movie;
}

public int getDaysRented() {
    return daysRented;
}
```

}

here i want to test the setMovie() Method.
So i want to test by mocking, that an exception is thrown as soon you give a Movie null parameter to the setter... so this was my try...

```
@Test(expected = RuntimeException.class)
public void letSetMovieFailByNullMovie() {
       Rental rental = new Rental();
       Movie mockedMovie = mock(Movie.class);

       doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(rental).setMovie(mockedMovie);

       rental.setMovie(mockedMovie);
       //mockedMovie should somehow be null here...

}
```

So my question is:
I want to check if an exception is thrown due to a null Movie. But how should i use mocking in this context, if i cant initialize a null-Movie?

Comment: what are you doing? you should always mock  the **Collaborators** not  the **SUT**. just pass `null` to the `setMovice` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Mockito in this case is not needed, simply invoking this method with null parameter would be enough. Like that:

```
@Test(expected = RuntimeException.class)
public void letSetMovieFailByNullMovie() {
    Rental rental = new Rental();
    Movie nullMovie = null;
    rental.setMovie(nullMovie);
}
```

In your code you were really testing if mockito works as it should, becouse Rental class code was not invoked, rather than that, exception was thrown because of `doThrow(..)...`.

Comment: thank you ! how do i know when/where to use mockito?